# C++ template member variable declaration error

Tags: class

I'm new to C++ and learning what Class is and related concept on it.
I faced some Error while practicing making code that contains class.

```
template <typename T>
class Node{
    public:
        T data;
        Node<T> *link;

        Node<T>(T element){
          data = element;
          link = 0;
        }
};

template <typename T>
class LinkedList{
    protected:
        Node<T> *first;
        int current_size;
    public:
        LinkedList(){
            first = NULL;
            current_size = 0;
        };

        T GetSize(){
            return current_size;
        };

        void Insert(T element);
        
        virtual bool Delete(T &element);

        void Print();
};


template <typename T> 
void LinkedList<T>::Insert(T element){
    Node *newnode = new Node(element);

    newnode -> link = first;
    first = newnode;
    current_size++;
}

template <typename T>
bool LinkedList<T>::Delete(T &element){

    if (first == 0)
        return false;
    
    Node *current = first;
    Node *previous = 0;
    
    while(1){
        if (current->link == 0){ 
            if (previous)
                previous -> link = current -> link;
            else
                first = first -> link;
            
    
            break;   // Point in which Error Occured 
        }
        previous = current;
        current = current -> link;
    }
    element = current -> data;
    delete current;
    current_size--;

    return true;
}
```

In "delete" Function, "'current': undeclared identifier  Error Occured.
I think I declared and defined it at the first of the function (Node* current = this->first).

I don't know why error happened.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace all `Node` usages with `Node<T>` and it [should compile](https://onlinegdb.com/EOGcgy7yX).

**Explanation:**

Each class that declares a template (`template <typename T>`) is familiar with it. Other classes aren't. Even if the template is declared with the same literal `T`, there isn't a conncetion between two different classes' templates.